# Combine data frame with all the data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames. All data frames in the list have the same variables. I have another data frame out side of the list. This data frame also has the same variables. How do I combine the data frame that are not in the list with all the individual data frames in the list?

Example:
In the list `my_list` there is some data frames `df1, df2, df3` etc. 
Not in the list there is another data frame `dfX`. All the data frames have the same variables. How do I combine `dfX` to **all** the df's in `my_list`. `dfX` should copied and added to all the data frames in `my_list`.

I suppose I need a `for loop` and `rbind`, but I can't seem to get it right. I'm not used to working with lists (and quite new to R in general). Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some dummy data:

```
foo <- list(df1=data.frame(A=rnorm(3),B=rnorm(3)),
    df2=data.frame(A=rnorm(3),B=rnorm(3)),
    df3=data.frame(A=rnorm(3),B=rnorm(3)))
dfX <- data.frame(A=rnorm(3),B=rnorm(3))
```

Then use `lapply()`:

```
lapply(foo,function(xx)rbind(xx,dfX))
```

Comment: Simple solution, as I expected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be (@Stephan Kolassa's data)

```
  Map(`rbind`, foo,list(dfX))
```

Testing the results

```
 res1 <- lapply(foo,function(xx)rbind(xx,dfX))
 res2 <-  Map(`rbind`, foo,list(dfX))
 identical(res1, res2)
 #[1] TRUE
```